# After upload a image in angular 2, shows 404 not found

Tags: javascript, angular

I know this is very a general question but I am failing to show a file in Angular 2 after upload. Although a file is existed on folder. It showing when I restarted angular.

Source tree my project

[image]

upload folder is saving image uploaded

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: We need to see your code, and if possible the folder tree of your project, so we can know where the file is.

Comment: are you testing this by using `ng serve` or by using `ng build` then going to the html page?

Comment: It's hard telling without seeing your exact setup, but chances are you are doing a build which just packages everything up and puts the resources into a distribution folder.  The reason your image wouldn't be showing up until a rebuild is because it is going into your src folder (which the web server does not have access to).

If this is the case you'll want to have the files upload to the upload folder that is actually accessible to the server (check the dist folder or equivalent after you rebuild to see where).

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to empty your cache before building again ?

Images are pretty often kept in the cache, so you should have a look there.

Also you might want to create a folder that you can access easily from any component for things like images. For example if you use Angular-Cli, check the **assets** part.
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Well, it should be something like :

```
<img alt="Alternative" [src]="'./upload/yourImage.something'">
```

If you are trying to use the image in `app.component.ts` or `app.component.html`.

But it's pretty hard to find what's wrong since you don't show your code.

Comment: Hi #kazu . My code is working. The file uploaded isn't showed if I don't rebuilt angular.

Comment: Sorry, but without seeing and testing it, I can't assume that it's working. If the problem is that you need to rebuild with Angular, maybe you should try to empty your cache ?